# Nullable object must have a value in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I am trying to do a calculation among a few columns in my database table. I have attached the model for reference:

```
public partial class CarSalesTable
    {
        public int CarSalesTableId { get; set; }
        public string? CarName{ get; set; }
        public decimal? Price{ get; set; }
        public decimal? Month1Sales{ get; set; }
        public decimal? Month2Sales{ get; set; }
        public decimal? TotalSales{ get; set; }
    }
```

I am testing a basic calculation that I want to apply to my `TotalSales` field where I want to take `Month1Sales` and add it to `Month2Sales`. Here is my code block for that,

```
 @{
    decimal Total = (decimal)@context.Month1Sales+(decimal)@context.Month2Sales;
    Math.Round(Total, 3);
  }
```

I am then assigning that value to my table row for `TotalSales`,

```
<MudTd DataLabel="Total"  >@Math.Round(TotalSales,3)</MudTd>
```

the project builds and runs until you open the page where this data would sit, then it throws a `Nullable object must have a value` error. Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong. I have seen other posts of this error but none like this and I am confused

Comment: Why are you casting to a decimal? It's already a (nullable) decimal. Are you checking that the value is not null before using it? Where are you setting those properties?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These values are nullable:

```
public decimal? Month1Sales{ get; set; }
public decimal? Month2Sales{ get; set; }
```

But you are forcibly casting to a non-nullable value:

```
(decimal)@context.Month1Sales+(decimal)@context.Month2Sales
```

What happens when they are `null`?  A `decimal` *can't* be `null`, so this will fail.

Instead of directly casting, you can use [null coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) to default to `0` for your calculation when the value is `null`.  For example:

```
decimal Total = (context.Month1Sales ?? 0) + (context.Month2Sales ?? 0);
```

This would effectively treat `null` and `0` the same in your calculations.

Comment: That works! I did not understand how that worked... the error wording confused me... Nullable object must have a value, but its nullable :(

Comment: @Kibofigs: Error messages like that can be a bit ambiguous.  I've worked with non-native English speakers who get confused by that sometimes.  It's not indicating that the nullable object *itself* "must have a value", but that it "must have a value" in order to be used the way it's being used but currently "doesn't have a value".